# How to fit an image inside a Bootstrap 3 div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, web

I am using a `div` tag in code as shown below:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <img src="images/dummy_image.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

The user can upload any kind of image and have it displayed here. I want to fit the image inside of the `div`, meaning specifically that I need to cover the full `div` using that image as it's resized.

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just add you images width to 100%.

**But as you are saying user will upload various kind of images, so can use `object-fit` property.**

Add the CSS like this:

```
.fit-image{
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
height: 300px; /* only if you want fixed height */
}

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<img src="images/dummy_image.png" class="img-responsive fit-image">
</div>
```

You will find the details about `object-fit` and `object-position` here : https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/

Answer (score 19):

**For Bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <img src="images/dummy_image.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

**bootstrap.css**

```
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to assume that by *fitting* you mean covering all of the width. This is because

1. You typically do not know the height just by using `col-sm-6` or `col-md-6` or `col-lg-4`.
2. There is a huge probability of loss in aspect ratio of the image if you try to resize it according to your own will.

Use `<img src = "images/dummy_image.png" class = "img-responsive" width = "100%" />` for fitting the column. This will fit your image width-wise into the column and will automatically modify the height (keeping the aspect ratio in mind), so you do not have to worry about image getting illogically resized.

Comment: Not wrong. But if you're using bootstrap, you can avoid using width="100%" with the bootstrap class "w-100". It's a bit cleaner.