# Bootstrap 4: fitting image content inside parent div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap grids, I have split the full page into two rows (25% height and 75% height). I like an image to be contained inside the first 25% row in a responsive manner. I like to avoid setting a fixed height and want the image to occupy as much height as possible. I have tried following most answers in similar previous questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466240/adjusting-and-image-size-to-fit-a-div-bootstrap/52287434), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870216/bootstrap-4-img-fluid-does-not-change-image-height/60279806#60279806) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482944/how-to-fit-an-image-inside-a-bootstrap-3-div), but none of them are working.

**What I did till now**: I tried using `object-fit`, but could not get it to work. Also it appears the parent div display property set to `flex` is the issue. But I am not able to find an alternative. Below is code and also please find MCVE in jsFiddle  [[link]](https://jsfiddle.net/kiran_happy/8ycvrun4/2/).

```html
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-25">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png" 
           class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-75">
    <div class="col">
      75 Percent Height
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you can try setting the image as background image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what u are expecting. I have added `h-100`classes to img  tag and `h-100` to img parent col tag

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-25">
    <div class="col h-100">
      <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-75">
    <div class="col">
      75 Percent Height
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.row {
  outline: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-25">
    <div class="col h-100">
      <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/bootstrap-icons.png" class="img-fluid h-100" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-75">
    <div class="col">
      75 Percent Height
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used only h-100 for img or else aspect ratio was lost. Thanks again.